# PHP isset for cookie not working

Tags: php, cookies

I am facing some trouble with a conditional statement that uses cookies in PHP.

I would like to change the state of an image based on whether a cookie is set or not. Here is my code (in file MAIN.PHP):

```
$cookie = "d_content_vote_".$databaseArray['id']; 
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) {
  // display image 1 if cookie is not set
}
else { 
  // display image 2 if cookie is set
}
```

The cookie value (of the timestamp) is set in ../INCLUDES/RATING.PHP, and I make an ajax call to that file. In order to debug, I did a `print_r($_COOKIE)` in RATING.PHP which gave me this:

```
Array
(
    [d_content_vote_1] => 1402726678
    [d_content_vote_4] => 1402727148
    [PHPSESSID] => effa8778efbe1b3dfb5bb301e359997d
)
```

However, when I do a print_r($_COOKIE) in MAIN.PHP I do not get the d_content_vote_* cookies, only the session info.

How do I transfer the cookie that is set in rating.php so that I can use it in main.php. I have never faced this problem before.

[Additional info: I'm building the site on a MAMP server now]

Comment: Check if the pages are being cached.

Comment: Thanks @IagoMelanias, but I am using a local MAMP server and refreshing the cache on every reload so that is not it.

Comment: `$databaseArray`. Show us your array

Comment: Did you `print_r($_COOKIE[$cookie])` or `print_r($_COOKIE)` when you were debugging?

Comment: This is working as you expect it to work, so your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @dpk2442 - I did a print_r($_COOKIE), which is why the session ID turned up as well.

colburton - I suspect you might be right. But that makes no sense to me - if the cookie is set, then the !isset condition should automatically display image 2. Instead, the page is always displaying image 1.

Comment: I have discovered an anomaly which may explain my issue, but i don't understand it. In my console when I do a print_r($_COOKIE), I see the [d_content_vote_1] => 1402726678.
However, when I check the developer console under chrome for cookies, it is not set. What could explain this?

Comment: For what path was the cookie set? Please show your `setcookie()` code, as the default path will be set for the current script's path not `/`. Different scripts would therefore not show the same cookies.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - thanks for that hint. 
I realised that i did not set the fourth parameter for setcookie which are (name,value,time, WORKING DIRECTORY) to allow the cookie to work in all the subdomains for my website. I've fixed that and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that my cookie was being set and the print_r was done in a file in a subdirectory (/includes) and therefore cannot be used in the root directory. In order to make it work in the root directory, I needed to add another attribute to the function:

```
setcookie($name, $value, $time, "/");
```

The last parameter "/" ensures that the cookie can be used in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

What about the cookie remove when a user make the log-out process? In case we use 4 parameters when setting the cookie, do we need to adopt the 4 parameters both in the log-out process?

```
setcookie($NomeCookieLogOut, "", time()-3600);
```

OR

```
setcookie($NomeCookieLogOut, "", time()-3600, "/");
```